# height of leaflet map in Shiny module app

Tags: css, shiny, module, leaflet, height

I want to add my small app as next module to my bigger app. Everything works fine except ... leaflet map height.
In independent app I had:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(700px) !important;}"),
  fluidRow(leafletOutput("map"))
)
```

When I transformed it to module I tried:

```
moduleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$style(type = "text/css", paste0("#", ns("map"), " {height: calc(700px) !important;}"))
  fluidRow(leafletOutput(ns("map")))
}
```

---

```
moduleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "#nsValue-map {height: calc(700px) !important;}"))
  fluidRow(leafletOutput(ns("map")))
}
```

unfortunately none of these suggestions work, the leaflet object is still 400px instead of 700px.

How the code should look like so that the map is 700px high?

---

Edit: Added example

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

moduleUI     <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(700px) !important;}")
  titlePanel("Leaflet Map")
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(ns("lat"), "Latitude:", value = 0),
      numericInput(ns("lng"), "Longitude:", value = 0),
      actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput(ns("map"), height = 300)
    )
  )
}
moduleServer <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = 0, lat = 0, zoom = 2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    lat <- input$lat
    lng <- input$lng
    
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(lng = lng, lat = lat)
  })
}
  
ui     <- fluidPage(moduleUI("module_id"))
server <- function(input, output) {callModule(moduleServer, "module_id")}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I am not sure what is not work. If take the example code you added and change `leafletOutput(ns("map"), height = 300)` to `leafletOutput(ns("map"), height = 700)` it work perfectly fine and the css code have no effect. Maybe when you added this module to your main app, there is other layout that control the height of parent element of the leaflet map?

Comment: thanks Sinh! It solve my problem, I have no idea why I messed with css instead of doing it in such an obvious way :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using id, I suggest you using the class instead which would not have problem when convert into module as well.

```
tags$style(type = "text/css", ".leaflet {height: calc(900px) !important;}")
```

Aside from that `leafletOutput` also have width

```
leafletOutput("map", height = 700)
```

Here a full working example

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Uncomment this if you want to use css style instead.
  # tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(700px) !important;}"),
  titlePanel("Leaflet Map"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("lat", "Latitude:", value = 0),
      numericInput("lng", "Longitude:", value = 0),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map", height = 300)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = 0, lat = 0, zoom = 2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    lat <- input$lat
    lng <- input$lng
    
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(lng = lng, lat = lat)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks for your interest in my topic. In a plain shiny app you wrote, it worked for me.
I've edited your example to show what I'm having trouble with using modules in Shiny App